# How does a multiclass gestalt work in terms of Base Attack Bonus and saves?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, gestalt

Every explanation in Unearthed Arcana about gestalts refers to them as having only one class on each path except the one about PrCs, so there are really some things that aren't very clear to me.

For example, let's imagine I have a Fighter 6/Wizard 4 // Rogue 10. I know a Fighter 6/Wizard 4 would have a +8 BAB, and a Rogue 10 would have +7. However the best UA can offer me is "Base Attack Bonus: Choose the better progression from the two classes." for a gestalt, which leaves me utterly confused.

Would the character have the BAB of a Fighter 6/Wizard 4, a Rogue 10, a Fighter 6/Rogue 4, a Fighter 6 + Rogue 10 - Rogue 6, or, well... something else?
Also, if Rogue 10 is the answer, would the character actually go from BAB +6 to BAB +5 at level 7, or would he maintain the BAB +6 until he hits lv10?

I'm looking for something official on this, but any answer will do in a pinch.

P.S.: I know that the BAB of Rogue 10 - Rogue 6 would be the same as Rogue 4, but I'm asking what the rule is here. It wouldn't be the same number for, say, Rogue 16 - Rogue 10 (12-7=5) and Rogue 6 (4).

Comment: Of course, I imagine that the same ruling for BAB would apply to the saves. If otherwise, please inform me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Flenyar quoted in his answer:

> Each time he gains a new level, he chooses two classes, takes the best
>   aspects of each and applies them to his characteristic.

This implies that if one class would gain a BAB at it's respective level, you do as well. Note that unlike normal multiclass characters, your stats do depend on what order you take the classes in.

Notice how Flenyar's progression (6 levels of Fighter/Rogue, then 4 levels of Wizard/Rogue) gives a BAB of +9, but the following progression gives you a full BAB of +10, even though the character is still a Fighter 6/Wizard 4//Rogue 10:

1. Fighter 1 / Rogue 1 (+1 [Fighters gain +1 every level])
2. Fighter 2 / Rogue 2 (+1 [Fighters gain +1 every level])
3. Fighter 3 / Rogue 3 (+1 [Fighters gain +1 every level])
4. Fighter 4 / Rogue 4 (+1 [Fighters gain +1 every level])
5. Fighter 5 / Rogue 5 (+1 [Fighters gain +1 every level])
6. **Wizard** 1 / Rogue 6 (+1 [Rogues gain +1 at 6th level])
7. Wizard 2 / Rogue 7 (+1 [Both Wizards and Rogues BAB improves])
8. Wizard 3 / Rogue 8 (+1 [Rogues gain +1 at 8th level])
9. **Fighter** 6 / Rogue 9 (+1 [Fighters gain +1 every level])
10. Wizard 4 / Rogue 10 (+1 [Both Wizards and Rogues BAB improves])

Total BAB at level 10 is +10.

This means that even a Wizard//Sorcerer gestalt (or any other two low BAB classes) can have a perfect BAB if you take just one level of another perfect BAB class:

1. Wizard 1 / **Fighter** 1 (+1 [Fighters gain +1 every level])
2. Wizard 2 / Sorcerer 1 (+1 [Wizards gain +1 at 2nd level])
3. Wizard 3 / Sorcerer 2 (+1 [Sorcerer gain +1 at 2nd level])
4. Wizard 4 / Sorcerer 3 (+1 [Wizards gain +1 at 4th level])
5. Wizard 5 / Sorcerer 4 (+1 [Sorcerer gain +1 at 4th level])
6. Wizard 6 / Sorcerer 5 (+1 [Wizards gain +1 at 6th level])
7. Wizard 7 / Sorcerer 6 (+1 [Sorcerer gain +1 at 6th level])
8. Wizard 8 / Sorcerer 7 (+1 [Wizards gain +1 at 8th  level])
9. Wizard 9 / Sorcerer 8 (+1 [Sorcerer gain +1 at 8th level])
10. Wizard 10 / Sorcerer 9 (+1 [Wizards gain +1 at 10th level])

Total BAB at level 10 for this Wizard 10//Fighter 1/Sorcerer 9 is +10 (perfect.) This cannot be determined without the order of the levels taken.

### However...

...the DM may overrule this, based on the wording of this rule:

> **Base Attack Bonus:** Choose the better *progression* from the two classes. (Emphasis mine.)

It is conceivable, then, that the Wizard 10//Fighter 1/Sorcerer 9 is a character with 1 level of perfect BAB progression (+1) and 9 levels of low BAB progression (+4), leaving him with only a BAB of +5.

I'm not sure of any official errata on the matter, but it makes a big difference in some cases. Ask your DM, or make sure your players know your ruling if you are the DM. Personally, I would stick with the latter "better progression" rule over the "better increase" rule, since it seems to be the intent of gestalt.

There is also the "Fractional Base Bonuses" house rule, presented on Unearthed Arcana p.73, which is designed to allow smooth leveling of gestalt multiclass characters without any of these exploitable loopholes.

### Saves

Since you mentioned saves in your comment, I'll touch on it briefly:

Saves would indeed work the same was as BAB, but beware that they are even easier to inflate artificially if you use the first presented "better increase" rule. This is because at first level of every class with good saves, that save "increases" from +0 to +2. Therefore it's even easier to end up with ridiculously high saves through multiclassing gestalt, if you don't simple lump all progression levels together before calculating character stats.

---

As a side note, consider two classes which gain 1d6 sneak attack every other level. Staggering them as I suggest staggering BAB increases still cannot double your sneak attack damage, since the book explicitly states:

> Class features that two classes share accrue at the rate of the faster class.

Comment: Actually, **I** am the DM, and I was wondering how exactly I should take this. The whole gestalt thing seems like it was poorly though out *and* like they weren't taking multiclassing into account except for PrCs (Note how, except on the part about PrCs, it always assumes that you only have 1 class and only on each path); I'll still use it, because it's the only way to make the characters be very powerful without going too far into the epic side. I think "lumping" is a good alternative to the cheese in the "better increase" and the ridiculousness ("you lose 1 BAB!") of the others.

Comment: About the saves, it is also possible to do this without gestalt with only multiclassing.

Comment: Also, the Fractional Base Bonuses thing is interesting, but it may be too much complexity to work out when making a 24//24 character, especially if he needs to stagger the classes due to other factors (feats, requirements and all that)

Comment: @Yandros—If you need gestalt to make broken, "very powerful" characters, you have never met the guys I play with... And yes, breaking saves is possible through only multiclassing, but generally not as prevalent. Lastly, as a rule of thumb, anything in a non-code 3.5e book is generally not thought out completely and pretty easy to find loop holes in, so require extra care by DMs like yourself.

Comment: *"non-core", not "non-code" — And yeah, fractional bonuses are a bit complicated if you're doing it all by hand.

Comment: I didn't mean it like that - some of my players are pretty munchkiny themselves, but I wanted to give them a chance to survive a campaign against the Wall of the Faithless without going that far into epic territory; not much of epic spells, epic feats, epic *anything*, which is especially important since we play using Epic Destinies; I also wanted some NPCs to be more powerful than them without getting too close to a god's power level...

Comment: The trick with fractional bonuses is recording the fraction, not just rounding down. For BaB that means counting quarters, and for saves counting sixths

Answer (score 4):

Unearthed Arcana clearly states (pag 73):

> Each time he gains a new level, he chooses two classes, takes the best aspects of each and applies them to his characteristic.

So, for every level you gain, your BAB improves in the best possibile way. Given your example (Fighter 6/Wizard 4//Rogue 10)

1. Figher 1 / Rogue 1 (+1 [Fighters gain +1 every level])
2. Figher 2 / Rogue 2 (+1 [Fighters gain +1 every level])
3. Figher 3 / Rogue 3 (+1 [Fighters gain +1 every level])
4. Figher 4 / Rogue 4 (+1 [Fighters gain +1 every level])
5. Figher 5 / Rogue 5 (+1 [Fighters gain +1 every level])
6. Figher 6 / Rogue 6 (+1 [Fighters gain +1 every level])
7. Wizard 1 / Rogue 7 (+1 [Rogues gain +1 at 7th level])
8. Wizard 2 / Rogue 8 (+1 [Wizards gain +1 at 2nd level])
9. Wizard 3 / Rogue 9 (+0 [Neither Wizards nor Rogues BAB improves])
10. Wizard 4 / Rogue 10 (+1 [Both Wizards and Rogues BAB improves])

So, in the end your BAB is +9. Same goes for base saves:

1. Figher 1 / Rogue 1 (Fort +2 [Fight.] / Ref +2 [Rogue] / Will +0 [Any])
2. Figher 2 / Rogue 2 (Fort +3 [Fight.] / Ref +3 [Rogue] / Will +0 [Any])
3. Figher 3 / Rogue 3 (Fort +4 [Rogue] / Ref +4 [Fight.] / Will +1 [Any])
4. Figher 4 / Rogue 4 (Fort +5 [Fight.] / Ref +5 [Rogue] / Will +1 [Any])
5. Figher 5 / Rogue 5 (Fort +5 [Any] / Ref +5 [Any] / Will +1 [Any])
6. Figher 6 / Rogue 6 (Fort +6 [Fight.] / Ref +6 [Rogue] / Will +2 [Any])
7. Wizard 1 / Rogue 7 (Fort +6 [Any] / Ref +6 [Any] / Will +4 [Wizard])
8. Wizard 2 / Rogue 8 (Fort +6 [Any] / Ref +7 [Rogue] / Will +5 [Wizard])
9. Wizard 3 / Rogue 9 (Fort +7 [Any] / Ref +8 [Wizard] / Will +6 [Rogue])
10. Wizard 4 / Rogue 10 (Fort +7 [Any] / Ref +9 [Rogue] / Will +7 [Wizard])

Your final saves are: Fort +7 / Ref +9 / Will +7

Answer (score 0):

From the example above:

Fighter 1 / Rogue 1 (+1 [Fighters gain +1 every level])
Fighter 2 / Rogue 2 (+1 [Fighters gain +1 every level])
Fighter 3 / Rogue 3 (+1 [Fighters gain +1 every level])
Fighter 4 / Rogue 4 (+1 [Fighters gain +1 every level])
Fighter 5 / Rogue 5 (+1 [Fighters gain +1 every level])
Wizard 1 / Rogue 6 (+1 [Rogues gain +1 at 6th level])
Wizard 2 / Rogue 7 (+1 [Both Wizards and Rogues BAB improves])
Wizard 3 / Rogue 8 (+1 [Rogues gain +1 at 8th level])
Fighter 6 / Rogue 9 (+1 [Fighters gain +1 every level])
Wizard 4 / Rogue 10 (+1 [Both Wizards and Rogues BAB improves])

This is the right way to do it.  When I first looked at including gestalt in my game many years ago, I struggled with this question.  Through puzzling it out, I saw that progression still only implies progression for that level, of the two classes in question.  Otherwise ugly wrinkles start creeping in, that are not easily forseen.  So, as one friend told me about life in general and game systems in particular, KISs it.  Keep It Simple.

Comment: Pretty sure getting +10 BAB for a combination of class paths that wouldn't get it otherwise is a much uglier wrinkle than anything else that could pop up, especially in cases like the one illustrated by dlras2 of a Wiz10//Ftr1/Sor9.
Seeing that KIS leads to the classes being better than their sums, for an already pretty OP variant, I'll err on the side of sanity. Thanks for the input anyway.